# Why is the "cash flow statement" a thing? (It seems it can be deduced from the balance sheet and income statement anyway?)

Tags: accounting, cash-flow

The question is basically in the title.

From what I see, once I have the balance sheet and income statement, I already have everything I need about my business. From what I've seen, when creating the cash flow statement (using the **indirect method**), I'm just copy-pasting info from the other two.

So what's the point of having it? Is this largely a historical convention that arose for reasons of at-a-glance convenience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an old business addage that "cash is king" which is still true in many ways, and the reason that the cash flow statement is important.

Suppose you have $1 Million in sales, but $500k of that it "on credit". That shows up on the Income Statement, but there is a risk that you may never receive the cash if the counterparty defaults.

Depreciation is another common difference between "income" and "cash flow". It is an expense, and increase net profit, but does not affect your actual cash, meaning that you don't get cash just because an asset depreciates. So it can make your "income" look larger than what it actually is if you only count cash transactions like sales and cash expenses.

The cash flow statement basically shows the source of cash in and out of the company. Did cash come from /go to operations (sales)? Borrowing (financing)? Purchase or sale of assets (Investing)?  Yes most of that is copy/paste from the other statements but looks at them with a different lens. Also, there are some items on the CF statement that are NOT directly visible on the others. Interest Expense and taxes are common ones - there is a difference between Interest and taxes that are *accrued* on the income statement versus interest and taxes that are actually paid out. The difference is typically small, but having visibility into what is actually paid is important.

Answer (score 5):

Since you mention "my business", I assume you are looking at this as a small business owner, rather than an investor reviewing financial statements of public companies.

In that case, it is very likely that the default approach you have taken to preparing your income statement and balance sheet is to do so only solely a cash basis. ie: you probably only recorded revenue for cash received from clients (rather than recording revenue & accounts receivable when the contract is completed, and then recording cash and decreasing cash receivable once you're paid), and you probably expensed a laptop or supplies but had no large fixed asset purchases.

This is called 'cash basis' accounting (rather than 'accrual basis' accounting, mandated for use by larger companies and often used by smaller businesses as well). In that case, yes, your cash flow statement will have little information not directly present on your income statement, because your income statement already didn't have any non-cash items. As the complexity of your business rises, and if you decide to increase the accuracy of your accounting, there will definitely be a difference between your income statement and cash flow statement.

Comment: My business uses "accrual basis", although there won't be many payables/receivables left at the end of the year (most invoices paid rather quickly).

@DStanley has confirmed (in his answer) my suspicion: Yes, it's mostly duplicated info (that can be deduced by anyone from the other two statements by at most adding/subtracting things). So yes, it really is (as I suspected) a mere convention that arose out of convenience (since, esp. when comparing many businesses, it's tedious to manually flip / do arithmetic between two pages).

Is my understanding sound?

Comment: (Of course in my previous comment, I exclude the exceptions @DStanley mentioned: accrued vs. paid-out taxes and interest. But is my understanding otherwise on the right track?)

Comment: I think your perspective is oversimplified. YOUR business may not see as much benefit of a separate CF statement, but many OTHER businesses do. Especially startups and other companies that have a lot of debt and equity financing, capital expenses,etc. It's not obviously at all from the BS and IS how much cash was spent buying assets, for example, or how much cash was raised in an equity offering. Those things are a small part of what makes the CF statement valuable.

Comment: @DStanley So far you've mentioned "Also, there are some items on the CF statement that are NOT *directly visible* on the others."  and now "It's not *obvious* at all from the BS and IS how...". (Emphasis added).

Those two reasons are already enough to make the cash flow statement very useful in practice. Now I (finally) get that part.

Finally I'd like to ask (to clarify things): Is there anything at all on the cash flow statement that *cannot possibly be deduced from the other two*? That's the only final missing piece for me now :) Thanks for the insights so far.

Comment: Interest and taxes are the most common - interest accrues but is paid later, as with taxes. Stock-based compensation is another non-cash item that isn't always broken out on the income statement.

Comment: @mmerprogra Can Net Income be deduced from the line items above it on the Income Statement? Yes, of course it can - it is the tabulation of + / - items above. Per your logic, should we then say that including a line that says "Net Income" is mere convention with no actual value? Of course not - there are many reasons why Net Income is a useful comparator, and providing that number itself rather than requiring a user to tabulate the income statement on their own, has value.

Comment: As to items not directly shown on the face of the IS / BS, which clearly show on the cashflow statement - that would depend entirely on the level of detail provided on the IS / BS. For example - is there a fixed asset register that would allow the discernment of property sold during the year vs bought during the year?